# Issues upgrading HP 650 Notebook PC with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a HP 650 Notebook PC and I’m trying to upgrade Windows to the new version, version 8.1. But when everything seems to be completed I get the error:

> We can not upgrade to 8.1 Windows
>
> Unable to complete the upgrade to Windows 8.1 . Restore your previous version of Windows on this PC.
>
> 0xC1900101 - 0x2004000D

Already uninstalled the AntiVirus! And I’ve been seeing the log and find my error code but does not provide me any information about where it originated, at least nothing that I perceive.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this error is an incompatible driver or hardware defect critical for booting the intermediary environment necessary to perform upgrade actions. As explained [on Microsoft’s site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/error-0xc1900101-0x20017-when-installing-windows/8631668d-1924-4259-8280-494f9f94f8b3):

> We are currently working with the companies to help them update their
>   problematic drivers whenever they are identified.  Some of the
>   identified drivers that are known to cause this error are listed here
>   and are the first steps you can try to resolve the issue.